# How do I open meet.google.com on Fennec without being redirected to meet.app.goo.gl?

Tags: mobile, google-meet

I want to join Google Meet on mobile browser, but it redirects to Play Store instead, even when I have "Request desktop site" checkbox checked.

How do I hide the fact that I'm browsing from Android and force meet.google.com to believe that is a real desktop and just show the usual UI, without trying to install any app?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like overriding User Agent to with `general.useragent.override` to `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:63.0) Gecko/63.0 Firefox/63.0` works: meet.google.com shows real UI instead of redirect to the non-installed app.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use the addon [User-Agent Switcher and Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/user-agent-string-switcher/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=collection) by Ray.

Just install it, open it up from preferences (at the very bottom when you tap three dot icon on tablets-Fennec on the top-right corner of the browser), choose top-to-down respectively: Firefox, Linux, Firefox 80.0 (or whatever the current version is). Then tap on "Options" and choose White-List mode and type in the box: `www.meet.google.com` and tap "Save". Quit the Fennec from the three dot icon and open it up again.